# Highmaps drilldown : hide label tooltip of level 2

Tags: highcharts

I've realized a drilldown of mappies (with display of mini charts when clicking on the region) and it works very well.
I have a small problem :

- on the higher level, when the mouse is over the region, informations are displayed in the tooltip (and if I clic, a mini chart is displayed). If I hover the region name label, a tooltip shows 'click to drilldown'. Everything is OK on this level.
- on the sublevel (when clicking on the region name from the higher level map), the map of the lower level is displayed and informations are displayed in the same way as for the upper level : mouse over the region -> informations are displayed in the tooltip (that is what I want). But when the mouse is over the name of the region, the tooltip with 'click to drilldown' is shown again and I would like that nothing appear at this level (because I can't drilldown again).
  An example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/hL8mdz2y)
  clic on 'Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes' : the map of the french region is displayed. Now go over the label 'Ain' : I would like no tooltip to be displayed on this label (only the tooltip over the blue color around the label).
  If I try to disable the tooltip, no more tooltip is displayed (nor the informations tooltip, neither 'clic to drilldown'). I want the informations tooltip continue to be displayed but not the 'clic to drilldown' at this level.
  I tried to do a close behavior that I expect with this code but it fixed the position of the tooltip. I want the tooltip to continue to be displayed near the mouse cursor.

  ```
    tooltip: {      
    useHTML: true,      
    pointFormat: '<span class="f32">'+level+'</span>',
    positioner: function () {
    var content = this.label.text.textStr;              
    if(content.indexOf('<span class="f32">2</span>')>0)
        return { x: 0, y: -100 };
    else
        return { x: 0, y: 250};
        }
    },
  ```

Any ideas about that ?
Kind regards

Comment: Is something like is done here satisfy you or you want to disable the whole tooltip? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/scbmwhx1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already found this first solution but I prefer that the whole tooltip is disabled (instead of a "blank" tooltip. Do you think it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the `tooltip.formatter` (not the tooltip config nested in the series config object) callback which allows setting displayed tooltip formats.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kg30con5/

```
tooltip: {
  formatter() {
    console.log(this)
    if (this.series.mapTitle) {
      var hoverVotes = this.hoverVotes; // Used by pie only
      var libRegion = this.LIB_REGION;
      if (libRegion == undefined) {
        libRegion = this.point.properties.name;
      }
      return "<b>" + libRegion + "</b><br/>" +
        "<hr/><b><i>Nb_Femmes : </b></i> " + unit_pre + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.value, mes_prec) + unit_suf +
        "<br/><i>Click to display more informations</i>";
    } else {
      if (level === 1) {
        return this.series.name
      } else {
        return false

      }
    }
  }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter